# Regex - How to group if three patterns are present

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to using regex to search for certain elements on a HTML page and capture if three patterns are met. Any help would be appreciated.

The elements are javascript and can be on multiple lines.

I am looking to find any pattern that matches

```
<script XXXXXXXXX>
ZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZ
ABCDEF
ZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZ
</script>
```

I need to capture all Zs as well as ABCDEF

XXXXXX can be anything.

I have tried

```
<script[^>]*>(([\s\S]*?)ABCDEF([\s\S]*?)<\/script>
```

But this seems to capture elements without ABCDEF as well.

```
<script>
QWERTY
</script>

<script>
ZZZZZZ
ABCDEF
ZZ@#<%
</script>


<script>
ASDFG
</script>
```

In this example I only want to capture

```
ZZZZZZ
ABCDEF
ZZ@#<%
```

Nothing before or after it.

Comment: can the ZZZZZZ be any other letter, or must be compulsorily be Z, eg FFFFF

Comment: Can be any character that is acceptable in HTML.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By placing part of a regular expression inside parentheses, you group that part of the regular expression and capture it.

Your regex match the pattern you want, but only the two separate Zs blocks  are returned.

Assuming that you need to retrieve groups, and it is ok for you retrieve more than group, you can try with

```
<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(ABCDEF)([\s\S]*?)<\/script>
```

which returns three groups.

If you need just one whole group with all three patterns inside, you please try with

```
<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?ABCDEF[\s\S]*?)<\/script>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it suffers the same issue as before, it will capture ANY <script> </script> tags until it hits ABCDEF then end at the next </script>

Comment: you mean that you have a list of <script> as in your example and you have to generate a regex applied at the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern, this should give your desired result

`<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)(?=(\bABCDEF\b))([\s\S]+)<\/script>`

match group 1 and 3

See the demo here https://regex101.com/r/wL4iL7/4

**Explanation**

```
<script[^>]*>: matches script and everything within it

[\s\S]+: matches all white space and non whitespace characters

(?=(\bABCDEF\b)): a look ahead to check if ABCDEF is present with boundaries \b surrounding it 

<\/script>: matches the closing script
```

Comment: This ends up working similar to the one I tried. It ends up capturing <script> </scripts> that are before and after any script with ABCDEF

Comment: i don't really get you. You don't want it to capture <script> and </script>?

Comment: i have understood you. i updated both my answer and the click, you can test the pattern again and check the link also